# MacBook Pro + OSX Lion + Samsung SA550 HDMI not playing nicely

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

I bought a Samsung SA550 monitor as a second monitor for my 2009 MacBook Pro that is running OSX 10.7 Lion. The monitor has 2 inputs, VGA and HDMI. If I connect the MacBook using VGA, everything is fine. If I connect it using a Mini DisplayPort-to-DVI converter and a DVI-HDMI cable, I get static and flickering:

[image]

The Mini DisplayPort-to-DVI converter that I use:

[image]

I have used this converter with a different monitor that had a DVI output port a while ago, so at least it used to work once upon a time. I am not sure if this problem is because of that converter or not. I have never used a monitor with an HDMI input before.

Appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a Mini Display Port to HDMI adapter or cable. You're probably not supposed to connect them in series.